# Terraform computed_ingress_with_prefix_list_ids usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Am I just dumb or is there no clear way or documentation on how to use `computed_ingress_with_prefix_list_ids`? There is documentation on the official security-group terraform [page](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws/latest), but I cannot seem to get a hold on how to use this feature.

My scenario is the following:

I have a module, official, of security group:

```
module "security_group" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"
  version = "5.1.0"
  for_each         = var.security_groups
  name             = each.value.name
  description      = each.value.description
  vpc_id           = module.vpc.vpc_id
  ingress_with_cidr_blocks = each.value.ingress_with_cidr_blocks
  egress_with_cidr_blocks = each.value.egress_with_cidr_blocks
}
```

And I have `variable "security-groups"` in which I have multiple security groups aligned like this:

```
variable "security_groups" {
  description = "value"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    first-sg = {
      "name"             = "first-sg"
      "description"      = "desc"
      "ingress_with_cidr_blocks"      = [
        {
          from_port   = somePort
          to_port     = somePort
          protocol    = "tcp"
          description      = "first-sg"
          cidr_blocks = "1.0.0.0/16"
        }
      ],
      "egress_with_cidr_blocks"      = []
      "tag"              = "some-sg"
    },
    second-sg = {
      "name"             = "second-sg"
      "description"      = "second-sg"
      "ingress_with_cidr_blocks"      = [
        {
          from_port   = somePort
          to_port     = somePort
          protocol    = "tcp"
          description      = "secod-sg"
          cidr_blocks = "1.2.3.4/32"
        },
        {
          from_port   = somePort
          to_port     = somePort
          protocol    = "tcp"
          description     = "second-sg"
          cidr_blocks = "5.6.7.8/32"
        }
      ],
      "egress_with_cidr_blocks"      = [
        {
          from_port        = 0
          to_port          = 0
          protocol         = "-1"
          cidr_blocks      = "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      ]
      "tag"              = "some-sg"
    }
 }
```

And the idea behind this is that I can use official security-group module, and iterate over this variable with for-each, creating multiple security groups with multiple ingress/egress rules.

Now I want to combine this, with my custom vpc_prefix_list which contains some batch of IP's I need to whitelist.

I tried adding `ingress_with_prefix_list_ids = [data.aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list.my-prefix-list]` to the module, but I've been spinning around all day and not being able to integrate it.

**MY QUESTION** - Can I integrate both security group solutions to my one module, or not?

My ideal scenario is that I have something like this:

```
data "aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list" "my-prefix-list" {
  filter {
    name   = "prefix-list-name"
    values = ["my-prefix-name"]
  }
}
```

```
module "security_group" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"
  version = "5.1.0"
  for_each         = var.security_groups
  name             = each.value.name
  description      = each.value.description
  vpc_id           = module.vpc.vpc_id
  ingress_with_prefix_list_ids = [data.aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list.my-prefix-list]
  ingress_with_cidr_blocks = each.value.ingress_with_cidr_blocks
  egress_with_cidr_blocks = each.value.egress_with_cidr_blocks
}
```

And I would create sg's from both `data.aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list.my-prefix-list` output, and from `each.value.ingress_with_cidr_blocks`.

The error:

> The given value is not suitable for module.security_group["first-sg"].var.ingress_with_prefix_list_ids declared at .terraform/modules/security_group/variables.tf:121,1-40: element 0: map of string required.

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: Hi Marko, yes, there are errors like
``` The given value is not suitable for module.security_group["first-sg"].var.ingress_with_prefix_list_ids declared at .terraform/modules/security_group/variables.tf:121,1-40: element 0: map of string required.```

Which also happens for all sg's I have in my variables. This occurs when I try to import ```ingress_with_prefix_list_ids = [data.aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list.my-prefix-list]```

Comment: If I understand the module code correctly, you need to have two arguments defined: `ingress_prefix_list_ids` (where you would add the data source as input) and `ingress_with_prefix_list_ids`. The latter one is a list of map type, so that means you would need somethng like [this](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-security-group/blob/master/examples/complete/main.tf#L465-L476) from the examples.

Comment: Or you might need only the `ingress_prefix_list_ids` argument.

Comment: No, not exactly. I've tried it, and still have the same issue. This way, it wants to iterate over all sg's I have in my vars, and implement them with this prefix list ID's. That's not exactly what I want as I described in the question.
If possible, I would like to leave you a screenshot of the result and you could tell me if it's okay or not?

Comment: If you have the output, just edit the question and omit any sensitive information from it.

Comment: Hey Marko, I've posted my answer. Anyway, it had to be a combination of your recomendation from documentation, and a new resource. It just wasn't possible to put it all in the same module, but this workaround works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE***

I've resolved the issue by extracting the security group from variables that I wanted to import as prefix list, and created a resource on it's own. Something like this:

The module stays untouched:

```
module "security_group" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"
  version = "5.1.0"
  for_each         = var.security_groups
  name             = each.value.name
  description      = each.value.description
  vpc_id           = module.vpc.vpc_id
  ingress_with_cidr_blocks = each.value.ingress_with_cidr_blocks
  egress_with_cidr_blocks = each.value.egress_with_cidr_blocks
}
```

Removed the wanted SG from 'for_each' variable, and move it to a standalone one:

```
variable "security_groups" {
  description = "value"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    first-sg = {
      "name"             = "first-sg"
      "description"      = "desc"
      "ingress_with_cidr_blocks"      = [
        {
          from_port   = somePort
          to_port     = somePort
          protocol    = "tcp"
          description      = "first-sg"
          cidr_blocks = "1.0.0.0/16"
        }
      ],
      "egress_with_cidr_blocks"      = []
      "tag"              = "some-sg"
    }
 }

variable "standalone-sg" {
  description = "value"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
        second-sg = {
          from_port   = 443
          to_port     = 443
          protocol    = "tcp"
          description      = "tcp"
          cidr_blocks = "1.2.3.4/32"
      },
    third-sg =  {
          from_port   = 443
          to_port     = 443
          protocol    = "tcp"
          description     = "tcp"
          cidr_blocks = "5.6.7.8/21"
      },
    fourth-sg = {
          from_port   = 5090
          to_port     = 5090
          protocol    = "tcp"
          description     = "tcp"
          cidr_blocks = "9.10.11.12/32"
      }
}
```

And create a resource that takes those values:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "standalone-sg" {
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id
  name        = "standalone-sg"
  description = "Standalone security group"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    prefix_list_ids = [data.aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list.first-sg.id, data.aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list.second-sg.id]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port        = var.standalone-sg.second-sg.from_port
    to_port          = var.standalone-sg.second-sg.to_port
    protocol         = "${var.standalone-sg.second-sg.protocol}"
    cidr_blocks      = ["${var.standalone-sg.second-sg.cidr_blocks}"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port        = var.standalone-sg.third-sg.from_port
    to_port          = var.standalone-sg.third-sg.to_port
    protocol         = "${var.standalone-sg.third-sg.protocol}"
    cidr_blocks      = ["${var.standalone-sg.third-sg.cidr_blocks}"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port        = var.standalone-sg.fourth-sg.from_port
    to_port          = var.standalone-sg.fourth-sg.to_port
    protocol         = "${var.standalone-sg.fourth-sg.protocol}"
    cidr_blocks      = ["${var.standalone-sg.fourth-sg.cidr_blocks}"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "standalone-sg"
  }
}
```